# Cassandra read consistency of ONE return no data sometime

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, datastax, nosql

I am new to Apache Cassandra so pardon me for asking dumb questions. 
I have recently deployed a Cassandra cluster on 8 nodes dsitributed among 4 DCs.

**Here is the configuraton:**

`Strategy: NetworkTopologyStrategy 
Replication factor: 8 
Write consistency: ALL 
Read consistency: ONE`

Right now I do not care about the PUT latency caused by the write consistency of all. But while testing, when I try "GET" something right after PUT, the request sometimes fails saying "Not found".

If I interpreted the datastax documentation correctly, the consistency level of ONE should return something since the write consistency is set to ALL. That is, when I do a PUT, all the nodes should acknowledge before sending the response back and a GET after that should return something even if it is a stale data.

Please let me know if I am missing something or I've grossly misunderstood the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In theory you're right, Cassandra **should** return a value when querying with **ONE**. Can you please provide the code to insert and to read the data ?

Comment: Are you sure that data is really exists in your database? Because CL ALL will fail to write if it have any node failed to write. (even if only one of your node cannot write, the whole write will fail because it is atomic)

PS. sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that writing with ALL and reading the same data with ONE should always return a result. You could also use the following formula:

(nodes_written + nodes_read) > replication_factor

To calculate what you can have to read and write consistency to guarantee consistency.

So a couple of things could be causing this issue for you:

- Race condition where your write request hasn't fully completed by the time you are reading the data.
- Your write with Consistency of ALL is failing and you're not properly handling it.

  - Your Cluster connection is using DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy, where the first write of ALL fails, so it retries the write with a lower consistency level.
  - Your Cluster connection is using LoggingRetryPolicy and you're not properly detecting a failed write.
- Some other bug related to how your application is reading a writing data.